# problematic ADIF records

Tags: c#, regex

[ADIF](http://www.adif.org/adif227.htm) is the standard for HAM Operator Radio`s LOG.

```
<EOR>
```

indicates the end of a record. I split one ADIF file into multiple records

The below record is causing a problem.

```
<CALL:6>SV2JAO<QSO_DATE:8:D>20101001<TIME_ON:4>1736<BAND:3>30M<MODE:5>PSK31<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<QSLMSG:62>TNX QSO, 73 FROM GREECE <pse paper qsl card for my collection>
```

Here is the code that splits the file into multiple records using regex.

```
string[] x = Regex.Split(record.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""), @"<(.*?):.*?>([^<\t\n\r\f\v]+)").Where(S => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(S)).ToArray();

var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    dic.Add(x[i].ToLower(), x[i + 1]);
    i++;
}
```

It's problem with the < and > inner ADIF Cell `<TAG:lenghtOfValue>Value`

The following are sample records.

```
<CALL:6>RK3DXB<QSO_DATE:8:D>20100926<TIME_ON:4>1334<BAND:3>30M<MODE:5>PSK31<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E

<CALL:6>EA1BRD<QSO_DATE:8:D>20100926<TIME_ON:4>1334<BAND:3>30M<MODE:5>PSK31<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E

<CALL:6>UV5EHT<QSO_DATE:8:D>20100926<TIME_ON:4>1334<BAND:3>30M<MODE:5>PSK31<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E

<CALL:5>G4MKI<QSO_DATE:8:D>20100926<TIME_ON:4>1536<BAND:3>30M<MODE:5>PSK31<RST_SENT:4>599 <RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<QSLMSG:22>73, thanks for the QSO

<CALL:6>EA1BRD<QSO_DATE:8:D>20100926<TIME_ON:4>1636<BAND:3>30M<MODE:5>PSK31<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<QSLMSG:19>TNX For QSO TU 73!.

<CALL:5>F5PEZ<QSO_DATE:8:D>20100926<TIME_ON:4>1705<BAND:3>30M<MODE:5>PSK31<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<QSLMSG:29>Tnx for the QSO best 73 Andre

<CALL:6>UA3LSX<QSO_DATE:8:D>20100926<TIME_ON:4>1749<BAND:3>30M<MODE:5>PSK31<RST_SENT:3>599<RST_RCVD:0><QSL_SENT:1>Y<QSL_SENT_VIA:1>E<QSLMSG:19>TNX For QSO TU 73!.
```

How can I modify my code or regex to resolve this issue?

Comment: Your sample code gives an error stating that the index is out of bounds in the array. This happens on the last element. What part of the message is supposed to be the key and the value in the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but how prevent from this (<something-text> inner ADIF cell) using the Regex syntax ?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with `(<something-text> inner ADIF cell)`. Assume your regex returns an array of 2 strings {"A","B"} The first iteration adds an item to the dictionary with A as the key and B as the value. The second iteration adds an item to the dictionary with B as the key and searches for a third item in the array. However the array only contains 2 strings. This is causing the issue. Your question doesn't explain why you are using the dictionary this way.

Answer (score 0):

solved :

```
            // workaround to prevent from '< something >'  inner ADIF Cell
            string[] x = Regex.Split(record.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""), @"<([^:]+):\d+[^>]*>").ToArray();
            List<string> l = new List<string>(x);
            l.RemoveAt(0);
            x = l.ToArray();
```